# swift mapkit annotations repeating the same CalloutAccessoryView image

Tags: swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I try to make a simple map with annotations,but when I try to run it, the images of detailCalloutAccessoryView are the same, but I'm sure I put two different images, How did this happen? Or does anyone have a better way to do this?

```
   var tripspot:[tripSpot] = [
    tripSpot( title: "1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.149062, 120.684891),  location: "台中市北區一中街", type: "rare",cllocation:CLLocation(latitude: 24.181143,  longitude: 120.593158),image : "025"),
    tripSpot( title: "2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.180407, 120.645086), location:"台中逢甲", type: "rare",cllocation:CLLocation(latitude: 24.180407,  longitude: 120.645086),image : "007")]
   // Build LocationManager
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // set data
    setupData()

}

func setupData(){
    for aSpot in tripspot {
            //set annotation
            let coordinate = aSpot.coordinate
            let title = aSpot.title
            let type = aSpot.type

            //set annotation
            let tripSpotAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            tripSpotAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
            tripSpotAnnotation.title = title
            tripSpotAnnotation.subtitle = type
            mapView.addAnnotations([tripSpotAnnotation])



        }
    }
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)
    {

        return nil
    }

    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("annotationIdentifier")as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if view == nil
    {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationIdentifier")
        view?.canShowCallout = true
        view?.sizeToFit()
    }
    else{
        view!.annotation = annotation
    }
    for aSpot in tripspot{

        // set pinview
        let detailCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 53))
        detailCalloutAccessoryView.image = UIImage(named: aSpot.image!)
        view?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailCalloutAccessoryView

    view?.pinTintColor = pinColor(annotation.subtitle!!)
    }
    return view
    }
```

thanks for any advice.

Comment: Unrelated, I might suggest you follow Cocoa naming conventions and give your `class` and `struct` types a name that starts with an uppercase letter (e.g. `TripSpot`). It makes it more clear when you're referring to a type and when you're referring to an instance of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not iterate through the whole array of `tripSpot` in `viewForAnnotation`. This method is for a particular annotation, but the way this is written, it's going to repeatedly set (and reset) the detail accessory for every annotation to be each image for every `aSpot` in `tripspot`, effectively giving every annotation the same detail accessory as the last `tripspot` (and doing so inefficiently).

Instead, make your annotation a subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` and add a property so it knows which image to use for a given annotation. If `tripspot` is an array of reference types, you might just add a property to refer to the relevant `tripspot` entry (from which it can then identify which image to show). And then, `viewForAnnotation` should retrieve that property from your custom annotation subclass rather than iterating through `tripspot` array. Also, by including a reference to the underlying `tripspot` entry, you also now have the capability of having the "did select detail accessory" routine to now know which tripspot it's associated with, and take the appropriate action.

As an aside, I don't know how many potential annotations there are, but it might be more prudent to save the name of the image in `tripspot` array, rather than the image itself. Images are relatively large and you risk running into memory issues if you have lots of annotations. It's generally more prudent to instantiate your `UIImage` objects as needed, rather than populating an array with the actual images.

Comment: Hi @Rob, Im not quite  understand your explanation, do you mean I need to add every image to each annotation? sorry, English is not my native language, it little bit difficult for me to fully understand.

Comment: @JohnnyHsieh - Perhaps easier, I might consider just making your `TripSpot` class conform to `MKAnnotation`, and then you can add it directly to your map, bypassing `MKPointAnnotation` altogether.

Comment: `class tripSpot: NSObject, MKAnnotation{
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var image : String?
    var location: String?
    var type: String?
    var cllocation: CLLocation
    
    
    
    init(title:String , coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D , location: String, type: String,cllocation: CLLocation, image: String ){
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.image = image
        self.location = location
        self.type = type
        self.cllocation = cllocation
        
        }
    
    
}`

Comment: I has already set `tripSpot` as MKAnootation @Rob, so should I delete the code `//set annotation
            let tripSpotAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            tripSpotAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
            tripSpotAnnotation.title = title
            tripSpotAnnotation.subtitle = type` ?

Comment: If `TripSpot` conforms to `MKAnnotation`, then you don't need `MKPointAnnotation` at all. You can just pass your array of `TripSpot` objects to `mapView.addAnnotations`. And when you go to set the accessory view, your annotation _is_ you `TripSpot`, so you have access to the appropriate image, without needing to go back to that array again.

Comment: thanks for your kind response @Rob I don't have clear mind with array. Sorry for asking so many stupid question. I can just do mapView.addAnnotations(tripSpot) right now. And trying solve image problem.

Comment: Done! Thank you@Rob!